# How ignore some fields in putitem in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I want replace existing record each time, So putItem is right action for me.
But each records have a creation date which i don't want update it. because creation date always the same.

Is any to implement this without query DynamoDB firstly? Thanks.
BTW: I did not use DynamoDBMapper.

Answer (score 2):

[PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html)

> Creates a new item, or replaces an old item with a new item. If an
>   item that has the same primary key as the new item already exists in
>   the specified table, the new item completely replaces the existing
>   item

[UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html)

> Edits an existing item's attributes, or adds a new item to the table
>   if it does not already exist. You can put, delete, or add attribute
>   values. You can also perform a conditional update on an existing item
>   (insert a new attribute name-value pair if it doesn't exist, or
>   replace an existing name-value pair if it has certain expected
>   attribute values)

**Answer:**
You should be using UpdateItem, not PutItem.

If you really do want to use putItem then you have to query first.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just do not want call the Dynamodb to read one more time. Maybe i have to do this.:)